# IBM Worklight 6.1 : How to authenticate user in the WLChallengeHandler inherited class?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

As in the push notification sample application, I am trying to integrate push notification sample app to our custom developed native ios application. In our case, the app will subscribe to push event source without user interaction. I have implemented this in the sample app, it is working fine.

In our native app, we need two requirements:

1. sending custom message by push notification
2. version management (enabling/disabling specific application versions)

(1) first requirement:

Before subscribing an adapter for push, first user must authenticate according to documentation, so i register  the handler with an ChallengeHandler inherited class because it has submitLoginForm function.

--- [[WLClient sharedInstance] registerChallengeHandler :  ]

ChallengeHandler uses SampleAppRealm:

```
<realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
</realm>
```

As a result, first scenario is working fine.  it is coming   WLOnReadyToSubscribeListener inherited class, OnReadyToSubscribe method. Default user can successfully subscribe without user interaction so we can send push notifications to the device.

(2) second requirement:

Inorder to enable and disable the application I need the register handler with an WLChallengeHandler inherited class because it has methods to handle success, failure  and challenge.

in this scenario, i am using wl_remoteDisableReam. Enable/disable specific versions functionality is working fine.

Problem:
on the other hand, when I try to run both functionality at the same time, I have problems. I couldnot authenticate the user in the WLChallengeHandler because it doesnot have submitLoginForm functionality. It is also not working when I instantiate an object from class ChallengeHandler and try to login. At the end, it is not coming WLOnReadyToSubscribeListener inherited class OnReadyToSubscribe method.

so how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is no reason for you to create a challenge handler for handling the remote disable. This is a feature that the framework provides for you.

All that you need to do is to add the security test to your custom test in authenticationConfig.xml and that's it.  You need only to disable the specific application version from Worklight Console.

The next time you will run the app, the framework will check against the Worklight Server whether the version is disabled or not, and will display an appropriate message if it is disabled.

Basically, the following is not needed at all:

> (2) second requirement:
>
> Inorder to enable and disable the application I need the register
>   handler with an WLChallengeHandler inherited class because it has
>   methods to handle success, failure and challenge.